How would I get IOS Bluetooth Devices (Just Device Names) using VS C# Maui
I am trying to make a quick program for a friend, and currently I don't have access to a mac device to use swift.
I have tried multiple solutions online, such as using Plugin.BLE, but it has mainly Android support. Is there a package with IOS Bluetooth support or is there a way to use C# in VS to get a list?

No matter what language you use you will need access to a Mac to build an iOS app. As for getting device names, it depends on whether you are looking for BLE devices or legacy devices like headsets etc.  for the former you may be able to get a device name. For the latter you will not be able to discover them with an app

please read [ask] before posting.  There are numerous existing questions about using BT in MAUI and Xamarin

Im going to try to get a mac on site to build and test, but for now, Im still using a windows emulator. I know I cant test right now, but Im only looking for 1 device among a list, which is if Airpods are connected. Airpods are a BLE device, so I should be able to discover them. But all of the Packages I find can only find a list of BLE devices from Android.

@Jason I have looked and tried, but as of my current knowledge, no post answers my question. I have tried other solutions, but none have worked yet. All are either Android based or use outdated Packages.

You probably won't be able to see if AirPods are connected using core Bluetooth
